# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in...on line 97

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have 2 pages.. a login page (login.php) and a user page (useracc-test.php)..everytime I login into useracc-test-php, I can retrieve data from my table called (users) but I cannot insert a new data into another table called (useradvert). I have 2  tables but, the data which I'm trying to insert into is a table called (useradvert). I get this error. Your help is very appreciated.. tq.

below is the script for my user page (useracc-test.php):

```
  <?php

//useracc-test.php

/**
 * Start the session.
 */
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);



// require 'lib/password.php';
require 'connect-test.php';


$userName= isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';




$query = "SELECT id, name, username, telno FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userName);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();


 ?>




<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#apDiv2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 51px;
    top: 238px;
    width: 237px;
    height: 93px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#apDiv1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 134px;
    top: 123px;
    width: 234px;
    height: 104px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#apDiv3 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 58px;
    top: 146px;
    width: 219px;
    height: 61px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#apDiv4 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 302px;
    top: 102px;
    width: 365px;
    height: 123px;
    z-index: 3;
}
</style>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryTabbedPanels.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryTabbedPanels.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
Your Personal details:</p>
      <p><?php while($row = $res->fetch_array()): ?>
<p><?php echo $row['id']; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $row['name']; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $row['username']; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $row['telno']; ?>





  <?php     

  // $userid = $_POST['id'];
  $stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO useradvert (id,name2,color2,hobby2) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("isss", $id, $name2, $color2, $hobby2);
  $stmt->execute();
  if (!$stmt)
  { printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);}
  else {

  echo "New records created successfully";}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

    ?>  





<form name="form2" method="post" action="useracc-test.php">
        <p>INSERT YOUR INTEREST:</p>
        <p>     
        </p>
          ID:
      <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">


  <p>Name :
          <input type="text" name="name2" id="name2">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="warna2"></label>
          Color :
          <input type="text" name="color2" id="color2">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="hobi2"></label>
          Hobby:
          <input type="text" name="hobby2" id="hobby2">
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
       </p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </form>       

               <?php endwhile; ?>

               </body>
               </html>        


--
-- Table structure for table `useradvert`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `useradvert` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name2` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `color2` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `hobby2` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `telno` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=96 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `telno`, `username`, `password`, `date`) VALUES
(95, 'Test Name', '09999999999', 'test@test.com', '$2y$12$fqdmAQk5c8qk8Eh2TWy2n.AdNO.lFjqmi2ruSzk8tsVXcK71OcPae', '2015-12-24 05:00:13');

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `useradvert`
--
ALTER TABLE `useradvert`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `useradvert_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`);
```

Comment: For your info, I have a limited knowledge in PHP..and I'm not an expert...

Comment: can u check on line 97, i want to know why that happening.

Comment: paste the code there at line 97 thx

Comment: Tqs for the reply Fiido Firdauz......I already updated the error above

Comment: tqs very much Darwin von Corax...But can you show me to the direction..I have a limited knowledge in PHP and still in the learning process..sorry to trouble u

Comment: Can you post the table definition for `useradvert`, please? Also, where are you getting the value you intend to insert into `useradvert.ID`?

Comment: Besides..my connect-test.php  is in mysqli...If I change to PDO..It requires a major overhaul..

Comment: You don't need to convert to PDO, although that would be a good exercise for later. `mysqli` implements prepared statements, as I explain in the second part of my answer below.

Comment: I intend to get the value when users key in manually..into user advert.(user page (useracc-test.php) display user details and also allows user to insert new details such as name (any new nick name), color and hobby.I will post  the table definition  in a minute...

Comment: regarding the id in table useradvert, I'm just not sure either to put it as auto incremented or leave it blank??.. because in my parent table..the ID is auto incremented..so i succesfully joined the two tables together without error..I've read many articles on the web.. but got deffirent opinions.. some say.. both ID's should be incremented and some say should not.. and some say don't use ID ..user username ad Primary key instead.. it's very confusing when it comes to relation tables.

Comment: .How do I remove the array problem??

Comment: Your ID value is coming from a form, so simply treat it like the variable it is. I've included it in the third part of my answer below.

Comment: OK noted..tqs Darwin.. one more thing...is it practical to insert user ID manually?..ir should I just delete the user ID in the form

Comment: and what is 'isss' ? below..

Comment: ok got it..interger and strings

Comment: I rephrase my question...should both keys in the table for "id" be auto incremented? or should I post this as a new question in this web?

Comment: I think I'd consider it a separate question.

Comment: Thank you Darwin.. for being generous.. i was able to correct the first query...but i'm still stuck with the second query..Call to a member function bind_params() on a non-object on line 100 ($stmt->bind_params('sss', $name2, $color2, $hobby2); I've search google adn asnwers from this site.. but could not find any match or solution..I've added $result = $stmt->execute(); below the query

Comment: A professional high end expert in PHP assistance and guidance is really appreciated and required at this time.. btw..tq so much to the rest of the members that tried to offer thier best guidance..I really appreciate it.. tq.

Comment: Are there any high end professional PHP experts out there that can help me at this moment??? I'm not building a multimillion website..it's a very simple low end (similar to student level you can say)  php pages. I have a very limited knowledge on this matter..

Comment: BY the way.. Darwin.. I removed the id for the last query.. coz I felt it was not neccessary.. im planning to change the index key (id) in useradvert to auto incremented but im still searching for notes and answers to before i make a choice.

Comment: Im almost giving up.. I already submitted for a moderator intervention...yet to wait for their reply..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
$sql = sprintf ("INSERT INTO useradvert (ID, name2, color2, hobby2) VALUES (%d, '%s', '%s', '%s')",  (int)
// V- here
$result['ID'], // <- here
// ^- here
mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $name2),
 mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $color2),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $hobby2));
```

As the error message says, you can't access a `mysqli_result` as an array - you have to `fetch()` each row into an array first. Also, even if it were valid syntax I can't see where the value for `ID` would be coming from, since it's not one of the columns queried to produce the result.

You really should be using prepared statements for this. Aside from preventing SQL injection attacks, a prepared statement handles all the quoting and type conversions for the query parameters. Your first query (the select) would be written as

```
$query = "SELECT name, username, telno
            FROM users
            WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userName);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $res->fetch_array();
```

Your second would look like

```
$userid = $_POST['ID'];
$query = "INSERT INTO useradvert
              (id, name2, color2, hobby2)
            VALUES
              (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_params('isss', $userid, $name2, $color2, $hobby2);
$stmt->execute();
```

(Note that in both cases I have omitted any sort of error handling, which I prefer to leave as an exercise for the reader.)

As for primary keys, you can use whichever column (or set of columns) will ***uniquely*** identify the row and will ***not change during the lifetime*** of the row.

Answer (score 0):

NO wonder data is not inserting.. forgot the if(isset($_POST['submit']))..LoL

Comment: I accepted your answer above because there were some parts that you help me resolve..tq Darwin...God bless you..